# Firestore & Play Services Task API (Tasks.whenAll() usage) in Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a call sequence. task1 must be called first and retrieved data should be used in task2.

My question is the following code requesting 3 times to firestore? Is it a pricey solution? Or should I simply make a nested calling task2 inside of task1's response?

I'm trying to find which way is more efficient to use. Thank you.

**Tasks:**

```
val task1 = Firestore.getUserDocument(userId).get()
val task2 = Firestore.getGlobalFields().get()
```

**Activity:**

```
            task1.addOnSuccessListener {
                it.toObject(User::class.java)?.let { user ->
                    this.user = user
                    til_name.setText(user.firstName)
                    til_surname.setText(user.lastName)
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                it.printStackTrace()
            }



            val allTask = Tasks.whenAll(task1, task2)
            allTask.addOnSuccessListener { _ ->
                task2.addOnSuccessListener {
                    val busStops = it.data?.get(BUS_STOPS) as ArrayList<String>
                    setBusStopAdapter(busStops)
                    hideProgressDialog()

                }
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                it.printStackTrace()
                hideProgressDialog()
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tasks are never executed more than once.  What you are doing is not "pricey" or inefficient.  You can have multiple listeners or continuations on a task, and they will all receive exactly the same result, because the task is only executed once.  You should do whatever is most convenient for you.